# Calling Web Api with jquery ajax returns error

Tags: jquery, web-applications, model-view-controller

Here is my jQuery code:

```
$.ajax({
                url: 'http://hostedsevice.com/webapi/Masters/GetStates/',
                data: { mName: request.term},
                //contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                dataType: 'json',
                type: 'GET',
                success: function (result) {
                    alert('');
                    if ($.isEmptyObject(result)) {
                        $('#JobStateTxt').css('border-color', '#B94A48');
                        $('#stateVal').show();
                        stateStatus = false;
                    } else {
                        $('#JobStateTxt').css('border-color', '');
                        $('#stateVal').css('display', 'none');
                        stateStatus = true;
                    }
                    response(result);
                },
                OK: function(result) {
                    alert(result);
                },
                error: function(result) {
                    alert(result);
                }
            });
```

and web api (which is in different project):

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetStates( string mName)
    {
        HttpResponseMessage response;
        try
        {               
                SB.BusinessLayer.Common.Common objComn = new BusinessLayer.Common.Common();
                var result = objComn.GetStates(mName);
                var state = result.Select(p => new
                {
                    label = p.StateName,
                    value = p.StateId,
                    id = p.StateId
                });
                response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, state, "json");
        }
        catch
        {
            response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        return response;
    }
```

Checking with Fiddler shows records(data) return by API but in jQuery success function is never get executed, instead of that error function runs and show statusText:'error'.
I cant not understand the issue here, help....

Comment: Have you tried to trace the API call using, for example, the Firebug network debugbar ? Maybe the JS console returns an error ; or the API itself

Comment: i have used fiddler and Web API retun results. I can see result on fiddler but not in jquery

Comment: Can you give us the fiddler link ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this is late response but I had a similar problem:

I found the line `dataType: 'json',` from the ajax call needs to be removed.

Comment: To clarify, it worked for me when I removed the dataType property, but left the contentType property. (For some reason calling old Web Service .ASMX it likes both properties.)

Answer (score 0):

I struggled a bit with this so I thought I'd add my findings. I'm not sure what version of jQuery you are using. In my case, I was upgrading from v1.12.4 to v3.4.1

I was using Ajax calls to communicate with web API. After I migrated the jquery version some of my ajax calls would successfully hit the endpoint but would always call the error callback function upon response.

```
   SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at parse (<anonymous>)
    at Ut (jquery-3.x.x.min.js:x)
    at k (jquery-3.x.x.min.js:x)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
```

I eventually realized that when in jQuery3.4.1 when calling a voidable endpoint...if you have explicitly stated the return type ie:

```
 dataType: 'JSON'
```

The response must match the stated type. In the above instance, it must be of type JSON. If you are calling a `void` endpoint. Nothing is returned and the error callback function is executed.

To fix this I did the above mention. Remove the datatype as nothing is expected back. This solved the problem for me as well. I'm still trying to figure out why this worked in `v1.12.4` and when this stopped working. If anyone could add to this would appreciate it.

Comment: Its been more than 5 years I even don't remember the issue. By looks of it that could be CORS issue. I might accessing service which was not on the same domain and this app was not white listed in the service.